# Boostrap can't handle very large screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using LG WebOS Emulator, i try to view my webpage. But it seems **Bootstrap cannot handle very large screen** (as seen in screenshot, there're 2 white screen region in left and right side). The Resolution of Emulator is **1920x907**

Screen Shot :
[image]

**The HTML :**

```
<div style="background-color:green" class="container">
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">3</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">4</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">5</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">6</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">7</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">8</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">9</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">10</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">11</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">12</div>                  
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>
    <div class="row"> <div align="center"><b>test</b></div> </div>              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><div id="dimensions" align="center"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is this Boostrap's **GRID limitation** ? if no, how to fix this ?
Thanks before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using

```
<div ... class="container">
```

try

```
<div ... class="container-fluid">
```

I'm not sure which version of `Bootstrap` you're running with, but in `3.1` (I believe) you have accessibility to this class. As a more custom alternative you can create your own `css` class, like so,

```
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

which would give you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.container` to `.container-fluid`

In bootstrap.css, there is a limit set for maximum width

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .container {
   width: 1170px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap** properties for large screens are limited to **1170 px** and therefore you need to either manipulate the code yourself or either download Bootstrap **XL grid** classes in a **CSS** file here;

[Bootstrap XL](https://github.com/marcvannieuwenhuijzen/BootstrapXL)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap for large display defaults to 1170px:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

However, you can make a customized build here to define your own default behavior:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes